# Where does the phrase "No ifs, no buts, no coconuts" come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms, phrase-origin

I've seen various entries for "No ifs, no buts, no cuts", but no explanation of the other phrase.

What is the etymology?

Comment: What is the etymology of, “I can’t find my other shoe?”

Comment: I'd venture it's just a convenient rhyme.

Comment: Closely related: [Origin of the idiom “If ifs and buts were candy and nuts”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47182/origin-of-the-idiom-if-ifs-and-buts-were-candy-and-nuts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An online search suggests that the expression you ask about may have been patterned on an earlier children's schoolyard (or lunchroom) expression with a very different meaning:

> No cuts, no butts, no coconuts.

(often rendered as "No butts, no cuts, no coconuts"), where *cuts* refers to "cutting in line" and *butts* to "butting in [line]."

Native U.S. English speakers may be familiar with the warning cry "No cuts!" in elementary school and middle school lunchroom lines. In this parlance, *cuts* referring to the practice of a kid coming late to the line and joining a friend who has already been standing in line for some time, ahead of others who have also been standing in line and don't appreciate being delayed further by line-jumping latecomers. The jingle-like longer phrase turns the warning into a stylized chant.

Google Books searches yield a meager supply of these various phrases in action. First occurrences of the various forms appear in this order: an instance of "No Cuts, No Butts, No Coconuts" as a [song title](https://books.google.com/books?id=uIIf03bGyAAC&pg=PA109&dq=%22butts+no+coconuts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiip-DFhKDUAhUEvLwKHfcBAsAQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22butts%20no%20coconuts%22&f=false) from 1999; an instance of "No Buts, No Cuts, No Coconuts!" as a [children's book title](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009Y667B2) from 2008; an instance of "No cuts, no buts, no coconuts" in [*Wreck-It Ralph*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NqgQT6eANcUC&pg=PT29&dq=%22buts+no+coconuts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwpuH_gKDUAhWIllQKHR2uBYgQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%22buts%20no%20coconuts%22&f=false) (2012); and an example of "No ifs, no buts, no coconuts" from [*Evil is Taking Over the Establishment - Origins*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OnOkBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA156&dq=%22buts+no+coconuts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwpuH_gKDUAhWIllQKHR2uBYgQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22buts%20no%20coconuts%22&f=false) (2014).

The *butts* versus *buts* issue isn't something you asked about, but it seems to me that in the case of the no-cutting-in-line chant, the *butts* spelling makes more sense—whereas in the no-ifs-or-buts saying, *buts* is clearly the intended word.

In an extended discussion of "No cuts, no buts, no coconuts," Barry Popik's [Big Apple](http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/no_cuts_no_buts_no_coconuts) site locates a first instance from the TV show *Hey Arnold!* from 1997. (Note that the example is spoken not written, so the spelling *but* is attributive. In fact, Popik's discussion doesn't address the *buts/butts* issue at all, nor does it acknowledge the existence of the "no ifs, no buts, no coconuts" variant.

---

**UPDATE (June 3, 2017):** I should mention two other confirmed early occurrences of related phrases. One is an instance of "no ifs, no buts, no cuts" from 1999 (probably) in [*Legal Action: The Bulletin of the Legal Action Group*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sired%20by%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22no+buts+no+cuts%22), where the meaning might be read as "no arguing or equivocating—cutting is not allowed"; the other is a much later instance, from [*Acid*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NDP-wsSkDs8C&pg=PA64&dq=%22no+buts+no+cuts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjflfTpk6PUAhVG4GMKHVEBBfMQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22no%20buts%20no%20cuts%22&f=false) (2008), which gives the expression as "no buts no cuts, no alligator guts"—a retort by one juvenile character to another, who has just uttered the one-word objection, "But."

Comment: As for the question "Why coconuts?" it should be clear that, once "no cuts" and "no butts" are aligned, the juvenile mind demands a three-syllable rhyme to close with. And according to [Rhyme Zone](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?typeofrhyme=perfect&loc=dmapi2&Word=mutts), the only options that don't repeat _cuts_ (namely, _supercuts_ and _undercuts_) are _cocoanuts_, _coconuts_, and _hazelnuts_. I'd say the kids got it right.

Comment: Coming from Britain, where queuing is genetic,  I'm not surprised I hadn't heard of this. Thanks!

Comment: I think the [Rhyme-as-Reason effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme-as-reason_effect) is relevant here. Using a rhyme (even if nonsensical) increases the chances of people seeing your statement as a universally accepted truth. Additionally, it can add an air of lightheartedness to the statement, e.g. Dutch has an idiomatic saying for "too bad": "Helaas, pindakaas!", which literally translates to "too bad, peanut butter!". It makes no sense but it sounds much more playful than just saying "too bad".

Comment: also the phrase "no cuts, no butts,no coconuts" was also mentioned in "Teen Titans Go" episode "Black Friday" Robin tells Starfire "no cut,no butts,no coconuts."

Answer (score 4):

As another answer mentions, it is a children's phrase.

I can't speak for others, but as a kid growing up in the U.S. playing baseball and football I heard coaches say this from time to time. The spelling in the use I heard would be "no cuts, no buts, no coconuts".

The references were slightly different than in other answers but this these differences are almost certainly regionalisms -- the spirit of the phrase is the same.

- "No cuts" equates to no cheating (no shortcuts -- relevant in line-cutting, but also more generally applicable)
- "No buts" means no excuses would be accepted ("butting" in line makes sense, but it wasn't the context of use when I used to hear this)
- "No coconuts" forbids stupidity ("coconut" means, in this context, someone who was empty-headed -- roughly the way the character Rocky Balboa uses the word)

Comment: Does Rocky Balboa really mean "coconuts are dumb"? [This quote](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/aa/9f/6f/aa9f6f5a93c4c6690b75741255b621ae--rocky-balboa--rocky-.jpg) (or [here](http://www.moviequotedb.com/movies/rocky/quote_30252.html)) looks like he's just talking about a person or head in general: *"I think we make a real sharp couple of coconuts. I'm dumb an' you're shy, whaddya think, huh?"*