# What is the original version of these two popular idioms?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

When I was but a young lad, I often heard the following saying;

> If “ifs”and “ands” were pots and pans, we would never do the dishes.

There is also another similar saying;

> If ‘ifs” and “buts” were candy and nuts, we would all have a Merry Christmas!

Which idiom came first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare [Origin of the idiom "If ifs and buts were candy and nuts"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47182/origin-of-the-idiom-if-ifs-and-buts-were-candy-and-nuts/294343#294343)

The original expression was "If ifs and **ans** were pots and pans, there'd be no need for tinkers" (*an* being an old synonym of *if*).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ifs_and_ans